# 2 breakers on one receptacle with hot neutral

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, receptacle, circuit-breaker

Here’s the situation:

3 receptacles in a bed room. 1 receptacle is controlled by the “middle of house” breaker, and the other 2 by the “front of house” breaker. Replacing the 2 receptacles on the FOH circuit. Turn off breaker, plug something into both receptacles + NCV test to verify they are off. Start pulling apart the first receptacle and queue the horrifying feeling of being shocked. Turns out the cables feeding the bottom of the receptacle were still energized and are part of the MOH circuit! The jumper was also still intact on the receptacle. Well after collecting myself and turning off the MOH breaker I start trying to diagnose exactly what is going on. I separate all wires on both sets of receptacles and turn power back on to FOH circuit. First receptacle has normal readings for H to N, H to G, and N to G, and and 0 on the pair of cables that shocked me (because MOH is still off). I go to receptacle 2 and all cables are reading 0. This is the confusing part. Receptacle 1 has 2 circuits providing hot which means there is no out going load. Wouldn't this mean Receptacle 2 should've had a line coming in? I turn off the FOH breaker and flip on MOH. With MOH on my rogue wires are reading 118 H to G AND 118 N to G with still no power at either of the runs in receptacle 2. It’s been like this for at minimum 5 years as this is how long I’ve lived here. Any thoughts on why someone would have two circuits in one receptacle and my hot neutral?

One response offered up to me elsewhere was that it sounds like I have a network? Also that in older homes (mine was built in 72 and has a split bus panel to give some reference), Hots on separate circuits would share a neutral with the neutral carrying the "imbalance"?...and until about 20ish years ago breakers didn't have to be handle tied when this was the case. This just sounds like a MWBC, right? Also, these breakers are on different phases which I guess does matter. Attached a quick visual to go along with the explanation. Thank you for any help or suggestions!

[image]

Comment: You have found the reason for handle ties for MWBC.  The problem is the intact jumper/tab between the two hot screws on the receptacle.  MWBC should be on different phase and trip the breaker/s if the tab is not removed.  It sounds like they are on the same phase in the panel.  A picture of the two breakers in the panel will help.

Comment: They are directly on top of one another. This would put them on different phases, correct?

Comment: That's why you **ALWAYS** check for power before working on various parts of a circuit.  A few years ago I was replacing outlets with child protective outlets  in my son's home, turned off the breaker and went on my merry way.  Got to the 4th outlet and guess what... it was on a different circuit and I got zapped.

Comment: I did, I just didn't check BOTH outlets on the receptacle as I had no reason to believe there would be two circuits feeding it. This is also why some don't trust tic testers as I used that too but was not indicated of voltage. But now I'll be sure to check ALL wires coming in to a box.

Comment: Please upload a picture of your panel. Yes, circuits that are next to each other (vertically) should be on opposite legs. **However**, 1/2 size (a.k.a., tandem or double-stuff) are on the same legs unless they are inner or outer pair of a quad. Also, if you can (safely) get a voltage measurement of MOH to FOH in Receptacle 1, that might provide a little more information.

Comment: I will get this when I get home. As for the measurement, which pairs am I testing across from MOH to FOH?

Comment: When you get 118v reading on a neutral wire it makes me suspect you have an open neutral and are reading a hot through some plugged in device.  It's particularly important to unplug and turn off any lights or fans on the circuit when working on suspected MWBC's.